# How to get the clicked object from a MouseLeftButtonUp event registered on a parent container?

Tags: wpf, events, routes, mouse, mouseleftbuttonup

I have ellipses drawn on top of a canvas, I've registered a MouseLeftButtonUp on the Canvas, and I and want to get what ellipse was clicked using:

```
(Ellipse)e.Source
```

But e.Source is always the canvas, I also tried e.OriginalSource and also did the same thing with PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp, but still same result. Event arg is MouseButtonEventArgs. What am I doing wrong? also is there a way to check if there is a child element of a canvas at a specific point.

Comment: You itself are saying that you registerd the event on Canvas, so the source and original source will always be canvas itself. Can you paste the relevant code here?

Comment: @RV1987 why does the same logic work for mouseleftbuttondown? Here is the code:


    `private void mainCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show((e.Source).ToString());
}
`

the exact same code shows ellipse in the mouseonleftbuttondown.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`e.OriginalSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp, not MouseLeftButtonUp.  Also, you may need to register your event using Ellipse.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp, rather than the MouseUp event on Canvas.  Something like this:

```
<Canvas ... Ellipse.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="MyHandler" />
```

And as H.B. mentioned, you want to use e.OriginalSource, not e.Source.

EDIT: Misread the question, editing to change to PreviewMouse*LeftButton*Up

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and this was the first answer to pop up. It was working for me on `MouseLeftButtonDown` but not on `MouseLeftButtonUp`. This was because of a logic error I had made with capturing the mouse in my `MouseDown` handler.

`MouseUp` events only fire on the element that is captured if you are capturing the element.

I had the following line in my `MouseLeftButtonDown` handler:

```
((FrameworkElement) sender).CaptureMouse();
```

Changing that to the following fixed the problem:

```
((FrameworkElement) e.OriginalSource).CaptureMouse();
```